# Return a double value from JDialog to JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm making a bank project and came into a problem. I have a `Depositwindow` class that extends to a `JDialog` and an `Accountwindow` class that extends to a `JFrame`. My problem is how to update my `Accountwindow` balance by adding the previous balance and the deposit amount in the `Depositwindow` class and display it in the `Accountwindow` balance?

Here is my `Accountwindow`:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener;

    public class AccountWindow extends JFrame {

    private final JButton jbtDeposit;
    private final JButton jbtExit;
    private final Account acct;

    public AccountWindow(Account acct) {
        this.acct = acct;

        // Create panel p1 for the buttons and set GridLayout
        // Set BorderLayout with horizontal gap 5 and vertical gap 10
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 10));

        JPanel pnlButton = new JPanel();

        pnlButton.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Actions"));

        pnlButton.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 1, 1));

        jbtDeposit = new JButton("Deposit");
        jbtExit = new JButton("Exit");
        pnlButton.add(new JButton("Balance"));
        pnlButton.add(jbtDeposit);
        pnlButton.add(new JButton("Withdraw"));
        pnlButton.add(new JButton("Apply Charges"));
        pnlButton.add(jbtExit);

        this.add(pnlButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // Create panel p2 to hold a text field and p1
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        p2.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Account"));
        p2.add(new JLabel("Account Number"));
        p2.add(new JLabel(acct.getAcctNum()));
        p2.add(new JLabel("Balance"));
        p2.add(new JLabel(String.format("%.2f",acct.getBalance())));
        // add contents into the frame
        add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        DepositListenerClass depositListener = new DepositListenerClass();
        jbtDeposit.addActionListener(depositListener);

        this.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowListenerClass());

        jbtExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                closeWindow();
            }
        });

    }

    //default the focus to the Name field when the window is first displayed.

    private class WindowListenerClass implements WindowFocusListener {

        @Override
        public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            jbtExit.requestFocusInWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
        }
    }
    /*
     * Fire a window closing window event so that the calling window can 
     * refresh.
     */

    private void closeWindow() {
        System.out.println("exiting");
        WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
    }

    class DepositListenerClass implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            DepositWindow frame = new DepositWindow();
            frame.setTitle("Deposit Window");
            //frame.setSize(400, 250);
            frame.setModal(true);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
            frame.setVisible(true);
            double amount = frame.getAmount();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `DepositWindow`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DepositWindow extends JDialog
{

    private JButton jbtOk;
    private JButton jbtCancel;
    private JLabel  jlbAccountNumber;
    private JTextField jtfAmount;

    public DepositWindow() {
        setModal(true);
        // Create panel p1 for the buttons and set GridLayout
        // Set BorderLayout with horizontal gap 5 and vertical gap 10
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 10));
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBorder( new TitledBorder("Actions"));
        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 1, 1));
        jbtOk = new JButton("OK");
        jbtCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        p1.add(jbtOk);
        p1.add(jbtCancel);

        this.add(p1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        p2.setBorder( new TitledBorder("Account"));
        p2.add(new JLabel("Account Number"));
        jlbAccountNumber = new JLabel("*****-56");
        p2.add(jlbAccountNumber);
        p2.add(new JLabel("Amount"));
        jtfAmount = new JTextField(10);
        p2.add(jtfAmount);

        // add contents into the frame
        add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jbtOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                setVisible(false);
            }
        });
  }

  public double getAmount(){
      return Double.parseDouble(jtfAmount.getText());
    }

  /** Main method */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DepositWindow frame = new DepositWindow();
    frame.setTitle("Deposit Window");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
 }
```

Account class:

```js
 

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Account
{
    private String acctNum;
    protected double balance;
    private String name; //customer name
    private ArrayList<Transaction> transactions;
    private String password;
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getName() + 
            "[acctNum="+acctNum+
            ",balance="+balance+
            ",name="+name+"]";
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Account) {
            return (this.acctNum.equals(((Account)o).acctNum));
        }
        return false;            
    }
    
    public Account() {
        transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
    };
    
    public Account(String acctNum, double balance) {
        this();
        setAcctNum(acctNum);
        setBalance(balance);
    }
    
    public Account(String name, String acctNum, double balance) {
        this();
        setAcctNum(acctNum);
        setBalance(balance);
        setName(name);
    }
    
    public Account(String name, String password, String acctNum, double balance) {
        this();
        setPassword(password);
        setAcctNum(acctNum);
        setBalance(balance);
        setName(name);
    }
    
    public String getAcctNum() { return acctNum; }
    public double getBalance() { return balance; }
    public void setAcctNum(String acctNum) {
        this.acctNum = acctNum;
    }
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public void withdraw(double amt) { 
        balance -= amt; 
        transactions.add(new Transaction('W',amt,balance,"withdrawal"));
    }
    public void deposit(double amt) { 
        DepositWindow d = new DepositWindow();
        if (d != null){
           amt = d.getAmount();
           balance += amt; 
           transactions.add(new Transaction('D',amt,balance,"deposit"));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the transactions
     */
    public ArrayList<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: 1) There is no need to, and it's probably counter-productive to, extend either `JFrame` or `JDialog`. 2) Make the dialog modal. 3) Pass the dialog a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel`.  4) As soon as the dialog is closed (i.e. next code line), query the value of the number model.

Comment: BTW 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) I'd probably just use a `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(..)` (instead of a `JDialog`) with a panel for the details.  The return value will determine if the user cancelled the transaction.  3) It is better to deal with integer values (in cents) when it comes to money.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the dialog modal, you can simply call `DepositWindow#getAmount` after the `setVisible(true)` call returns (as it will block until the user dismisses the window)...

```
public class DepositWindow extends JDialog
{
    //...
    public DepositWindow() {
        setModal(true);
        //...
```

Then...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    DepositWindow frame = new DepositWindow();
    frame.setTitle("Deposit Window");
    //frame.setSize(400, 250);
    frame.setModal(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
    double amount = frame.getAmount();
    // Update the account details
}
```

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: I dont know what Im doing but my dialog returns nothing.

Comment: You set it to be modal first?

Comment: Maybe the problem must have been my implementation in the account class. I've updated it with the account class.